# TF 2.0 Beta: how to re-initialize the weights of a custom built model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

So I have a model built by subclassing models and layers. I'm doing some experiments, I'd like to go back a newly initialized NN. How can I do that?
Currently, I'm just running the code that defines it again. There should be a neater way of doing it.
I tried model.build (running it twice). Didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to re-initialize with *the same* random weights then you can just save the pre-training weights to disk with:

```py
# build model, model.compile(), etc

model.save_weights('initial_weights.h5')

# model.fit(), etc
```

then when you want to go back you can load the initial weights again with:

```py
model.load_weights('initial_weights.h5')
```

Comment: In the light of absence of any better solution I will go with this. Thanks.